# Open full .aspx web page in modal dialog box

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, modal-dialog, aspx, popup

I have searched everywhere to find a solution for opening an entire .aspx web page inside a modal dialog box. I do not want to open a specific web part, I would like to embed the entire page, with all it's original functionality, into a modal box that I can bring up with a button.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below script to open webpart page in model dialog

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowDialog(URL) {
                        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                        options.url = URL;
                        options.width = 600;
                        options.height = 600;
            options.title = "Title";
                        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
                       }
</script>
<a href="javascript:{ ShowDialog('yourpage.aspx?IsDlg=1'); };">Link</a>
```

Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0f1f43e-b481-44a5-b03b-15d481fc180e/display-web-part-page-in-modal-dialog-without-ribbon-controls?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: My webpages are still not showing up. I've tried multiple pages and messed with the file paths, tried with the extension and not, but nothing is working. I'm still getting errors when trying to load saying the "webpage is not found", or there was a "technical error". Does it make any difference that the pages have either lists or infopath forms on them?

Comment: Page content type need to be webpart page. Wiki page will not open in pop up.

Comment: Hi Josh, Please accept the answer if it helped you.